# How to fill in stat_summary_2d ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a very basic ggplot question. I am wondering if there is a way I could have ggplot automatically fill in all the empty squares in this plot with squares representing zeros.

[image]

An example of code of what I wanted

```
Matrix <- as.data.frame( cbind(rnorm(10), rnorm(10), rnorm(10)))
d <- ggplot(Matrix, aes( z = V3, V1, V2)) 
d +  stat_summary_2d(bins = 10)
```

I am also aware that there exists the geom_raster function but that gave me:

[image]

Instead of the smooth surfaces like:

[image]

That I was expecting from the ggplot docs.

The code for the raster was:

```
ggplot(Matrix, aes(V1, V2)) + 
geom_raster(aes(fill = V3))
```

Comment: I added an example above

Comment: Are your x and y axis (V1 and V2) integers or floats?

Comment: In your wanted result - what palette are you using? Is it default blue or something else? I'm asking because it might help if it's specific color mapped to 0

Comment: My axis are floats. But so are the datapoint in the old faithful datasets that created the third image(https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_tile.html)

Comment: Also my color palette is the default blue. Do you have any ideas for changing the mapping?

Comment: If you don't mind a quick and dirty solution, you could draw a filled rectangle in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the nice "smooth surfaces" that you see, `ggplot2` expects that you are going to give it a bunch of plotted points and it will calculate the density using the `MASS::kde2d()` kernel density function. What I think you are looking to do is use a dataset where the values of each point are known and you want to smooth out the colors of the spaces in between.

I have never found how to do this using the `ggplot2` functions on their own. Because you are assuming that there is a spatial relationship between the points (the closer the more intense, the further, the less intense), this problem will likely be best solved using a package that focuses on spatial interpolation and IDW (inverse distance weighting). This chapter explains how to do it and how it works:
https://mgimond.github.io/Spatial/interpolation-in-r.html

I believe the reason `geom_raster()` is producing small points is because the points are not at evenly spaced intervals on the x and y axes. If I understand the code correctly, the function looks for the smallest common denominator and create pixel tile sizes to match. Yours are very uneven and so the tiles are small. `stat_summary_2d(bins = 5, fun = "sum")` will get you closer but it will not interpolate the space in between.

**As a workaround**, if your dataset is not huge and your z value can be made into integers, you can create a point for each value of z using `tidyr::uncount()`. I wouldn't use this for a very large dataset but in a pinch, it will do what you want.

```
df <-
  tibble(
    x = rnorm(10),
    y = rnorm(10),
    z = floor(rnorm(10)+10)
  ) %>% 
  uncount(z)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  stat_density_2d(
    aes(fill = stat(density)), 
    geom = "raster", contour = FALSE
  ) +
  geom_jitter(width = 0.1, height = 0.1)
```

[image]